# Return date only (not time)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that stores date information as a varchar(8).  All of the data is entered as yyyymmdd.  I would like to cast this information in a view to display as a date.  When I try:

```
SELECT CAST(HIRE_DATE AS datetime)
```

The values are returned with the time.  For example a record that has 19951107 casts as 1995-11-07 00:00:00.000.

How can I have it just return "1995-11-07" without the time value?

Comment: Have you tried:  `select(cast hire_date as date)`?

Comment: The column is broken :( Best thing to do is to fix the schema!

Comment: Which SQL Server version "Date" became available in 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @DMason (`cast(HIRE_DATE as datetime)`) is the correct one if you have SQL Server 2005 or earlier.

SQL Server 2008 introduced the `date` datatype which means you can achieve what you want with `cast(HIRE_DATE AS date)`.

If there are invalid dates in your varchar(8) column then `cast()` will cause the query the fail. SQL Server 2012 introduced the `try_` conversion functions which return a null marker if the cast is impossible. So, you can achieve what you want with `try_cast(HIRE_DATE AS date)`.

From Books Online: [Conversion functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231076.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to be what you're looking for:

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(HIRE_DATE AS DATETIME), 102)`

Note that the return value is `VARCHAR`, not a true DATE, DATETIME, etc.

If you need it as a DATETIME datatype then omit the `CONVERT`.

`SELECT CAST(HIRE_DATE AS DATETIME)`

[CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) should be helpful.